# Excel how to use CUBE functions without access to OLAP tools

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2010 don't have access to PowerPivot or connection to OLAP server.

I'm trying to build a dashboard to display ranked data and allow user to filter by 3-4 different criteria. I was able to get it function by using long nested if statements. But the required filter criteria is getting too many that I can't stick to this method.

I've done some research and found this nice OLAP tool to be able to convert pivot table to formulas. But I don't have access to the tool on my computer, and I'm new to MS BI, I'm wondering if anyone could share with me ways to use the cube function without the connection or any other ideas to build this dashboard. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your current data source for your dashboard? Are you dumping data into excel sheets and turning them into pivot tables?

Comment: Yes, all data are in excel sheets. I'm creating a dashboard based on reports created by others, so I don't have access to the raw data.

Comment: So really you want to use cube type against data in Excel sheets? To use these kind of things you need for example to have dimensions defined... which you won't have in Excel data. Have you tried just building a pivot table off your data? that gives you a lot of what you're after.

Comment: I just thought it would be helpful to reorganize the layout of the pivot table and adding fields using cube function. But I'm not familiar with the concepts...

Comment: By 'cube function' I guess you mean MDX - a language for querying cubes. But you can't run MDX against a data source that's an Excel sheet. There are quite a few hits when searching on  "creating dashboards in excel ". Why don't you try a few of those methods and post back specific issues.

Answer (score 1):

To use Excel's cube functions your data source must be either a Microsoft Analysis Services database (multidimensional or tabular) or an Excel Data Model (Excel 2013 and higher) or Excel 2010 and higher with Power Pivot. You can't use cube functions with data in Excel worksheet ranges. You may be able to get some flexibility in your dashboard layout with regular PivotTables possibly with the GETPIVOTDATA function; the latter requires some work though.